# Kotlin generics expecting unexpected type

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I've defined the following base class with two generic types and using it two levels deep (for lack of a better phrase). Here's my use case.

```
abstract class BasePresenter<out M, out V> {
    var model: M? = null

    var view: WeakReference<V>? = null

    fun setM(model: M?): Unit {
        this.model = model

        if (setupDone()) {
            updateView()
        }
    }

    fun bindView(view: V) {
        this.view = WeakReference(view)
    }

    fun unbindView() {
        this.view = null
    }

    abstract fun updateView()

    fun view(): V? {
        return if (view == null) null else view?.get()
    }

    fun setupDone(): Boolean {
        return view() != null && model != null
    }
}
```

I'm extending it using

```
open class VenueListPresenter: BasePresenter<Venue, VenueView>()  {...}
```

Which works fine, as expected, but then I'm running into issues when I'm trying to use the `VenuListPresenter` as a type parameter in a different class.

```
open class VenuesViewHolder(itemView: View): MvpViewHolder<VenueListPresenter>(itemView) {
```

This gives me an error stating that the expected argument in `MvpViewHolder` is  BasePresenter, and that what was found was a `VenueListPresenter`. My `VenueListPresenter` extends a `BasePresenter<Venue, VenueView>` where `Venue` and `VenueView` are of type `Any?` because by default they extend it. So why isn't it working?

MvpViewHolder is defined like so

```
abstract class MvpViewHolder<P>(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) where P : BasePresenter<Any?, Any?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `out` variance to your generic parameters in `BasePresenter` so that a type like `BasePresenter<Venue, VenueView>` will be a subtype of `BasePresenter<Any?, Any?>`.

```
abstract class BasePresenter<out M, out V>
```

As a short explanation, the `out` keyword specifies *covariance*, e.g. if you have a class `YourClass<out T>`, it means that when `A` is a subtype of `B`, then `YourClass<A>` is also a subtype of `YourClass<B>`.

See more details about Kotlin generics and variance in the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance).

---

Edit based on comment below:

If you can't make the above change, you could use *use site variance* at the `MvpViewHolder` class instead, to accept `BasePresenter` subtypes with any subtypes of `Any?` in their type parameters:

```
abstract class MvpViewHolder<P>(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) 
        where P : BasePresenter<out Any?, out Any?>
```

You could do this exact same thing with [star projection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections) (just a different syntax in this case):

```
abstract class MvpViewHolder<P>(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) 
        where P : BasePresenter<*, *>
```

In both of these cases, anything of type `V` or `M` returned from a `P` will be of type `Any?`, and you won't be able to pass `V` or `M` instances into methods of `P`. If you need to be able to do that, you could consider adding more generic parameters:

```
abstract class MvpViewHolder<P, M, V>(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
        where P : BasePresenter<M, V>
```

Comment: I was reading about them earlier and didn't go with using `out` because it specified that that's used for producer classes. In my case, (I have made the edits for you to see the entire presenter class) having them be prefixed with `out` caused the line `var model: M? = null` to get a compile error saying that it occurs as an invariant position in type M. It looks like making it private solves the issue, but do I always have to be conscious of how I'm using the types within the class in order to declare them as out or in?

Comment: In the class I posted, I use it as both a producer and consumer